# With StreamWriter doesn't work \n (C#)

Tags: c#, newline, streamwriter

I have a problem with the C# Stream Writer.
I use the following Code:

```
//Constructor
public EditorTXTFile
{
   FileStream f = File.Create(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Output.txt");
   f.Close();
}

//Function AddText
public void AddLogFileText(string text)
{         
   string text = "l1\n\rl2\n\rl3\n\nl5";

   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Output.txt", true);
   writer.Write(text);         

   writer.Close();
}
```

When I open Output.txt it shows for \n or \r a █(which means not showable symbol) and the whole string is in one line...
Later should the text hand over the function, so I can't write the text with .WriteLine because I don't know if the actual string is on the same line or in a new line.

What make I wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try `\r\n` rather than `\n\r`

Comment: Or even better, `writer.WriteLine` which does it for you

Comment: The answer here has some helpful information as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885900/order-of-carriage-return-and-new-line-feed

Comment: But it should also go when I just wirte a \n (By l5). Or not?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference to your question, but you should wrap your StreamWriter calls in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `Environment.NewLine` as line separator or `"\r\n"` if you want to do it by hand.

Comment: The beauty of `Environment.NewLine` is that you don't have to worry about the correct combo of `\r\n` for the particular environment in which your code is running.

Answer (score 2):

Line Separator(newLine) is `\r\n` not `\n\r`,

change your text as :

```
       string text = "l1\r\nl2\r\nl3\r\nl5";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `string text = @"l1\n\rl2\n\rl3\n\nl5";`. To prevent character stuffing.

Answer (score 0):

This is binary format:

```
writer.Write(text);
```

This is line sequential format:

```
writer.WriteLine(text);
```

You have to use `WriteLine` format...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.NewLine` like this:

```
streamWriter.Write(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Environment.NewLine, n).ToArray()));
```

Comment: the variable n is unknown

Answer (score 0):

i tried to write a class and seprate "\n"s 
but i found rich text box!!

yeah! it works:

```
        RichTextBox rch = new RichTextBox();
        rch.Text = cmn;
        foreach (string l in rch.Lines)
            strw.WriteLine(l);
```

Comment: you can use rch.NewLine="\n\r"; to change new line environ