# Why is the newline character not working?

Tags: c#, io

I am new to C# file handling, and I am making a very simple program. The code is as follows:

```
class MainClass 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Punit\\Desktop\\hello.txt");
        sw.Write("HelloWorld" +Environment.NewLine);
        sw.Write("ByeWorld");
        sw.Close(); 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The above code produces the following expected result in the text file:

```
HelloWorld
ByeWorld
```

I also wrote somewhat modified version of the code like this:

```
class MainClass 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Punit\\Desktop\\hello.txt");
        sw.Write("HelloWorld\n");
        sw.Write("ByeWorld");
        sw.Close(); 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here instead of using the

```
Environment.Newline
```

I directly added "\n" to the "HelloWorld" line.
This produced the following output (int the text file):

```
HelloWorldByeWorld
```

My question is that why is the second piece of code not working? (Not producing the newline in the text file)

Comment: Translating C# to Natural Language: Because `\n` does not get interpreted as *New Line Feed* in your working Environment :)

Comment: It is `\r\n` on Windows.

Comment: I'm taking a guess here: You're looking at the result with Notepad. Notepad will not interpret a lone U+000A as a line break, only U+000D, U+000A, therefore what you wrote to the file *is* there, but you don't see it as such. At least not in Notepad. In any decent text editor you would.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please try

```
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Punit\\Desktop\\hello.txt");
    sw.Write("HelloWorld \r\n");
    sw.Write("ByeWorld");
    sw.Close(); 
    Console.ReadLine();
```

you can read it over [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/newline)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with

```
sw.WriteLine("HelloWorld");
sw.WriteLine("ByeWorld");
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to 'sw.WriteLine'. Like c++, it invoke newline. You could also
read this:
[Create a .txt file if doesn't exist, and if it does append a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907682/create-a-txt-file-if-its-not-exist-and-if-it-exist-write-a-line-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I had tried it and it was working fine. I wanted to know the reason, why "\n" didn't work.

Comment: Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885900/order-of-carriage-return-and-new-line-feed

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sw.Write("HelloWorld\\n");
```

instead of

```
sw.Write("HelloWorld\n");
```