# How can I identify invisible characters in python strings?

Tags: python, string

**SHORT VERSION**

I am retrieving a database value, which contains a short, but full HTML structure. I want to strip away all of the HTML-tags, and just end up with a single value. The HTML surrounding my relevant info, is always the same, and I just need to figure out what kind of line breaks, tabs or whitespaces the string contains, so that I can make a match, and remove it.

Is there a place I can paste the String online, or another way I can check the actual content of the String, so that I'll be able to remove it?

**LONG VERSION, and what I've already tried:**

The String is retrieved from a HP Quality Center database, and printed in the console of the automated test execution, the string is interpreted to show as two whitespaces. When pasted into word, eclipse or the QC script editor, it is shown as a linebreak.

I've tried to replace the whitespaces with `\n`, double whitespace and `&para;`. Nothing works.

I am translatnig this script from a working VBScript. The problematic invisible characters are defined as `vbcrlf` and `VBCRLF` there. For some reason they use lower case in the replace String before the relevant parameter value, and upper case in the string that comes after my relevant substring. They are defined as variables, and are not inside the String itself: `<html>"&vbcrlf&"<body>"&vbcrlf&"<div`...

This website suggests that I should use `\n` https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070506205148AAmr92N, as they write:

> vbCrLf = "\n" # Carriage returnlinefeed combination

I am a little confused by the inconsitency of the upper/lower case use here though...

**EDIT:**

After googling Carriage returnlinefeed combination, i learned that it can be defined as `/r/n` here: [Order of carriage return and new line feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885900/order-of-carriage-return-and-new-line-feed).

But I spent an awful long time finding it, and it doesn't answer my question, of how I better can identify exactly what kind of invisible characters a string contains. I'll leave the question open.

Comment: Don't worry about case; VB is not case-sensitive. (Classically, at least. I'm not sure about VB.Net, but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: Awesome. Unexpected bonus learning has occurred ;)

Comment: You could discover the contents of your string by simply calling `repr` on it and printing the result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by invisible characters? You can always write `print( [data] )` and that will give you an idea of what the string contains (it will show you `\r` (carriage return), `\n` (new line) and hidden unicode/hex values such as `\x00`).

Comment: Because I am retrieving data inside HP Quality Center, and because I do not still know where my console output goes in this system, I am using another print function, which prints strings to another log. For that reason, repr doesn't work for me in this situation, but using the bracket syntax does. This was really easy, I just didn't know how to find the information. If you guys would write up an answer, I would be happy to accept. This is exactly what I was looking for. My output String, when QCprint([string]) =  `<html>\r\n<body>\r\n<div`... etc

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To view the contents of a string (including it's "hidden" values) you can always do:

```
print( [data] )
# or
print( repr(data) )
```

If you're in a system which you described in the comments you can also do:

```
with open('/var/log/debug.log', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write( str( [data] ) )
```

This will however just give you a general idea of what your data looks like, but if that solves your question or problem then that is great. If you need further assistance, edit your question or submit a new one :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Leave it to the Swedes to solve the Norwegians' problems ;). Tack så mycket.

Comment: @KjetilNordin Haha, no problemo granne. Happy to be of service ;)

Comment: Note that this answer does not answer the question in the title. I suggest editing the question title to reflect the problem that was solved with this answer.

Comment: +I now that the title matches the answer. Nice job!

Comment: How would you do this with a pandas column within a jupyter notebook?

Comment: and how can i remove these non-printable characters except for new line \n and \r in a pandas column?

Comment: @R.A Using the `re` module, and use a regular expression that filters out the things you need would be one option. You can also write a filter-lambda that uses the [strings.printable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable) selection.