# How to remove "\n" from Python string?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

## What I am trying to do:

I am trying to run this line of code:

```
RAW_FILE="filename.txt"

os.rename("source.file", RAW_FILE)
```

I simply want to take a file matching source.file and rename it to something contained in the RAW_FILE variable. testing this works fine with anaconda python shell.

## The problem:

When running with the script I have this error:

```
os.rename("source.file", RAW_FILE)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax 
is incorrect: 'source.file' -> 'filename.txt\n'
```

I have a print in the script and it shows the filename.txt without the '\n'

I have tried (amongst many other things):

```
.rstrip()
.strip()
.replace('\n', '')
```

## My question:

How can I remove this seemly invincible '\n' and what is the cause of this?

Comment: Please show a verifiable example. Your code when [run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8gxPN7N08fVNi0zJzUvMTdVr6SihCu/WK8IzNNQKs4vLUpO1QNJK@kowJRr/v8PAA) as-is doesn't provide the error you said. Read [mcve] for more details.

Comment: I ran your code and all that is missing is the `''` on filename.txt.  Perhaps you pasted the wrong code.

Comment: @user202729 thanks for the feedback i have now properly fomatted my question.

Comment: @Simon so i am actually using single quotes for my filename.txt, i have also updated this in my question. But your comment did spark an idea! how do i add double questions to a variable in python?

Comment: Can you show what's there inside your script? Probably with `xxd` (hexdump)? We need verifiable example to solve your problem.

Comment: [Also see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341351/how-can-i-identify-invisible-characters-in-python-strings).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.